# Intellisense and strengthening concepts

Tags: c++, intellisense, vscode-extensions, c++-concepts

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename State>
concept IsState = requires(State obj) {
    {
        auto(obj.terminal)
    } -> std::same_as<bool>;
};

template <typename State>
concept IsPerfectInfoState = requires(State obj) {
    requires IsState<State>;
};

struct Foo
{
    bool terminal;
};

template <IsPerfectInfoState State>
void foo()
{
    State state;
}

int main()
{
    foo<Foo>();
}
```

I'm using VSCode with the all the recommended C++ extensions and GCC 13.0.1

This all compiles and makes logical sense. The problem is that using `IsPerfectInfoState` to constrain a template parameter will not give autocomplete access to the `bool terminal` member. Is there some work-around for this?

Comment: Does making it subsumption-friendly help? `concept IsPerfectInfoState = IsState<State> && requires(State obj) { /* Other checks*/ };`

Comment: bingo!!! tysm bro